# Variable within quote within quote?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use inner html and dynamically set an onclick statement that contains a variable:

```
cell5.innerHTML="<input type='button' value='Remove' onclick='removerow('manual_" + (num) + "')' />"
```

So lets say the num variable was set to 4. The output should be `onclick="removerow('manual_4')"`

Any help?

Comment: Do you have to use HTML attributes for event handlers? This problem doesn't exist if you set handlers from JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escaped nested quotes using `\`:

```
"...onclick=\"removerow('manual_" + (num) + "')\"..."
```

Comment: Please consider reading Felix answer, that's how DOM elements should be inserted into the DOM.

Comment: @Jose Faeti I did that and agree that it's better, although this answer was directed toward the "nested quotes" problem.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing would be to avoid all this:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
input.value = 'Remove';
input.onclick = function() {
    removerow('manual_' + num);
};

cell5.appendChild(input);
```

Depending on the relationship between the button, the cell and the row to be removed, you could also do DOM traversal inside the handler to get a reference to the row.

Comment: @Felix Yeah i realized later that this is the correct and more efficient method but at this point, it would simply be too much effort to change and i dont have time (this one input is part of a single <td> part of a single row that is being appended via javascript)

Comment: @Jonah: Whatever works best for you, just showing alternatives, no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

```
cell5.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removerow(\'manual_' + (num) + '\')" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quotes using `\`

So

`onclick=\"removerow('manual_" + (num) + "')\"`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a click event instead. It makes that sort of thing clearer:

```
$(".cell5") // whatever selector you want
  .html('<input type="button" value="Remove"/>')
  .click(function(){
    removerow('manual_' + row);
  });
```

Also consider using the row number as the input instead of a string. If they all have the same form you can simplify things with just:

```
removerow(row);
```

Clearly that is an API design decision, but it would simplify this expression if it makes sense.